# How to create a new OneToOne object in another's model Serializer?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models: `Content` and `Address`. Each content has one address so the models are something like this:

```
class Content(models.Model):
   ....

class Address(model.Model):
   content = OneToOneField(Content)
   ....
```

I now want to adjust the `ContentSerializer` so that I can pass data for an address in it.

```
class Content(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = ContentAddressSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = ('address')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if "address" in validated_data:
            address = validated_data.pop('address')
            Address.objects.create(**address)
        validated_data['editor'] = self.context['request'].user
        return Content.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

I'm succesfully creating an `Address` but when the `to_represantation` method is called, I get an `AttributeError`. Is there a better and easier way than to override the `to_representation` method?

Comment: If your models names are Content and Address why are you using, Content_Address??

Comment: The name is actually Content_Address but changed it for the post. I've changed them.